# Javascript, cannot change product pages dynamically

Tags: javascript, html, css, dom, e-commerce

I am teaching myself Javascript at the moment and I am creating a small website project for fun. My issue is:

I have a homepage that has a button in a navbar called "Products". When I press it, I am redirected in a page where I have a grid layout with 5-6 categories (as images). When I press the images, I am redirected to the relevant products. For example Products > Cars > Fiesta 2009 and more cars.

The thing is that for every different product category I have a different HTML page, but I know that I can just have an HTML page and change its content dynamically(DOM). Is there a good guide that describes this specific functionality? I have tried many different approaches but I don't really know how to do that and my site doesn't work.

Posting it after 15 hours on working on my code and not finding a solution myself*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can consider using a UI framework/library such as ReactJS, Angular ...
Then use a routing handler (react-router, @angular/router ...).

Another alternative is to use plain javascript (VanillaJS).
I submitted a [sample](https://github.com/wasssim1/spa-noframework-demo) few days ago nearly around this topic.

Comment: Wow, thanks for the sample, I think it will help a lot! Yeah I am going for vanilla since I wanna dive into a framework a little later :)

Comment: So instead of having the paths in the navbar, I will just create some paths that are opened when you click the product category image?

Comment: Could be! I will soon add to the repository a **Dynamic Routing** feature.
(eg. `/products/:id`)